# Verilog gate definition difference

Tags: logic, verilog, hdl

This is two type half adder definition on Verilog.

Is there a difference between them? Which should I choose? Why?

**halfAdder1**

```
xor(s,x1,x2);
and(c,x1,x2);
```

**halfAdder2**

```
assign s=x1^x2;
assign c=x1&x2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is known as **structural** model, using the gate-level primitives.
Second one is known as **RTL** model (Register Transfer Level). Both models are fully synthesizable and likely to generate the exact same hardware.

Said that, the RTL modelling is a bit closer to the higher-level programming languages and thus more readable for humans. In addition it is abstracting the gates to the arithmetical/logical operators, giving the synthesis tool more flexibility to choose the appropriate gates.

On the other hand the gate level is more appropriate if you have a schematic of your circuit and want to directly translate it into HDL.